# Rails not finding gem. "Could not find .. in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I recently set up Ruby on Rails with rbenv. But for some reason I am getting: "Could not find shoulda-matchers-3.1.1 in any of the sources" when I try to do a rails generate scaffold command. Here is my gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY:     /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/username/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /home/username/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/username/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin
     - /home/username/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/username/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/username/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/username/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/username/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/username/.rvm/bin
     - /home/username/.rvm/bin
     - /home/username/.rvm/bin
```

And when I run gem list, it shows:

```
sass-rails (5.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.1)
shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
spring (1.7.1)
sprockets (3.6.0)
```

I've tried gem install shoulda-matchers, bundle install, bundle update, gem install bundler, gem install bundle, gem update --system, etc. It says I have it already but it still keeps giving me that error. Please help. D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to prefix your commands with `bundle exec` each time, like `bundle exec rails g`.

If you're sick of typing `bundle exec` you can install the binstubs like

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

See https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Plugins#bundler-integration for more detail.

Comment: Running my rails generate command with bundle exec before it still didn't change anything. Same message. :(

Comment: What about installing the binstubs?

Comment: That worked! Is there anything I need to be aware of though? It seems like that using binstubs is not normally a good idea?

Comment: The reason is because all the binaries provided by your gems (like the `rails` command) are not automatically available in your PATH when you're using rbenv or rvm. The binstubs command puts `bin/` into your PATH so that you can invoke those commands. Read https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs for more info on how it works.

Comment: The other thing to be aware of is that by using binstubs you could have different versions of gems available in different project directories. For example you could have a Rails 4 project in one dir and a Rails 5 project in another. By using binstubs you'd always invoke the correct bins for the version of Rails that you're currently working in.